# How to add a onclick attribute to a list of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this array for checkbox:

```
array(
        'name' => __('Latest Product',''),
        'desc' => __('Select if you want to display latest product',''),
        'id' => $prefix . 'checkbox',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'std' => ''
    )
```

I want to add an attribute for `onclick="chk(electronics, this.checked);"` on this.

How can I do it?

Comment: In which context do you have this checkbox?

Comment: Your question is incomplete, provide complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Store the ID in a variable, and access that variable using JavaScript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("<?php echo $checkbox_id; ?>").onclick = function() {
    chk(electronics, this.checked);
}
</script>
```

You can also collect multiple IDs in an array and run through that array later in your script. But avoid the `onclick` attribute in markup, this is bloat and bad code style. :)

Comment: it's not working in my file..... can i inlcude this line  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"  onclick="chk(electronics, this.checked);"> in above array.....

Comment: You could add a separate key named `onclick` and use it in the script that converts the array into markup. You didn’t mention that script, so I cannot say how this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with JQuery then use below code example.

**JQuery:**

```
//Temporary set electronics variable with blah, replace it with your code
var electronics = 'blah...';

//For set onclick attribute after page load
$('input:checkbox').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('onclick', 'chk(electronics, this.checked);');
});
```

For live example please check my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Narendrad/k8bb4dnv/1/). In this fiddle you can check functionality by click on any check box, it will prompt message with checked true/false...

This is based on your question, if it not as you want then please give some more detail what you want.